# Change of account from Facebook to Gmail

Tags: support, user-accounts, login

I am now using my Facebook account to log in to Math Stack Exchange

I would like to delete my Facebook account so another option I am left with is to use Gail account..

In my profile I have already changed private email to Gmail id but then it is not working when I wanted to log in from Gmail account

It is considering me as new user when I am logging in from Gmail account

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Changing email address does not do anything for the login function. You should click *my logins* in the profile, and then *add more logins* in the pop-up window.

Comment: This is working :D Thank you :)